# No consigo centrar el título con el contenido FLEX

Tags: css, html5, css3, flexbox

Tengo dos dudas y no soy capaz de encontrar la solución.

- En el **`H1`**, no consigo centrar a la misma altura que el **article - *colum2***, tiene la misma medida tanto arriba como abajo `width: 657px`.
- ¿Por que cuando quiero dar una *separación* entre los idiomas ES/EN, y agrego un margin-left, `H1` se mueve?. ¿Debo dar un tamaño también al `div` clase **idioma**?

Todo esto lo intentado con flex.

Lo que quiero conseguir es lo siguiente.

[image: Post It]

**Mi código**:

```css
.title {
    display: flex;
    /* medio de ALTO izquierda */
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
    justify-content: center;
}
.cajavacia{
    /* border: 2px solid blue; */
}
.tit1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 657px;
    align-items: center;
}
.idioma{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid green;

}
.idioma__es{
    color: darkgray;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.idioma__es:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.idioma__en{
    color: darkgray;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.idioma__en:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; */
}

.colum1 {
    background-color: burlywood;

}

.colum1 li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;

}

.colum1 li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#color1 {


    background-color: red;
}

#color2 {


    background-color: BLUE;
}

#color3 {


    background-color: green;
}

#color4 {


    background-color: white;
}

#color5 {


    background-color: black;
}

.colum2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 657px;
    height: 595px;
    background: url(postIT.png) no-repeat;

}

.colum3 {
    background-color: mediumturquoise;
}

.colum3 {
    background-color: mediumturquoise;
}

canvas {
    border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Post-it</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <!-- <script src="idio.js"></script> -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="title">
        <div class="cajavacia"></div>
        <!-- <div class="tit2">
            <h1>Dibuja en tu Post It</h1>
        </div> -->
        <h1 class="tit1">Dibuja en tu Post It</h1>
        <div class="idioma">
          <a href="index.html" class="idioma__es">ES</a>
          <a href="EN/indexen.html" class="idioma__en">EN</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section id="container">
      <article class="colum1">
        <ul>
          <li id="color1"><a href="#">#1</a></li>
          <li id="color2"><a href="#">#2</a></li>
          <li id="color3"><a href="#">#3</a></li>
          <li id="color4"><a href="#">#4</a></li>
          <li id="color5"><a href="#">#5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </article>
      <article class="colum2">
        <canvas id="dibujar" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
      </article>
      <article class="colum3">
        <h5>GROSOR DE LÍNEA</h5>
        <input type="range" />
      </article>
    </section>
    <!-- <script src="postit.js"></script> -->
  </body>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código aquí? Si le das a Cntrl+M lo puedes insertar para que sea ejecutable aquí dentro de Stackoverflow.

Comment: No lo sabía, editado y muchas gracias @Dєηyη Crawford

Comment: No entiendo la primera duda, ¿qué es lo que quieres centrar en el H1? yo lo veo centrado.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal puedes usar el siguiente bloque de css para la alineación de los idiomas

```
.idioma > a {
    min-width:25px; /*Este instruccion va a hacer que no te mueva la caja padre al momento de poner uno de los hijos en negrita*/
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.idioma > a:first-child {
    opacity:.5;/*Una opacidad al primer hijo para darle efecto de selección*/
    font-weight: normal;
}

.idioma > a:after {
    margin:0 auto;/*Para centrar elementos de tipo bloque utilizas los margenes de izquiera y derecha en automatico*/
}
```

Todo el codigo esta basado en el padre selector de los idiomas